# Bootstrap data from remote API in Backbone

Tags: rest, backbone.js

Delving into techniques to "bootstrap" my Backbone application, however I'm struggling to see how the suggested methods, like this one: http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data, don't just take the application a step back and tightly couple your API to your frontend.

I have a REST API and a backbone JS app, is the best solution to make a DB/API call in a serverside language and then output the JSON object directly into index.php (or whatever),

Is there a better solution for bootstrapping a Backbone application other than mixing in server side code into my JS app?

Comment: i agree with the answers from fencliff and dormisher. just be aware that the only data you should bootstrap is data that absolutely must be available at all times. if you don't always need the data in your app, don't bootstrap it. of course, there are nuances and subtleties to this, but it's a good rule to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by *bootstrapping* you mean the following scenario:

- You have a single page application that fetches data from the server using AJAX requests
- When the page initially loads, the first thing you application does is fetch all the data
- You want to improve the startup speed / user experience by including all the necessary data in the initial request

If this is the case, you have no other option but to render the initial data into your `index.php`, or whatever you call the html document that loads the application. How else would it get there?

If this is an unacceptable solution, you should try to optimize the loading by other means.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest, useful backbone JS apps that need data to operate are coupled to your back end in almost every situation anyway. As soon as you write:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: '/api/MyModel'
});
```

you are saying "you have to use my endpoint to get/update/create data, therefore you cannot operate on your own". So whether you write data to your page on the server and inject it into your Backbone models, or whether you retrieve data after the page is loaded, you are basically doing the same thing.

If I were you I wouldn't worry about it! After all, are you going to lift your client application from your back end and stick it on another back end somehow? I'd say the chances of that ever happening or so minute, that whether you were bootstrapping data by writing JSON to your page on the server would certainly be the most minor of changes.